# Set property of ComboBox within UserControl instance

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

I have a UserControl that contains 2 ComboBoxes and 2 TextBoxes. I have 2 instances of the UserControl in the MainWindow.

The Visibility of the second instance of the UserControl is binded to CheckBox which is placed  in the MainWindow - the UserControl becomes Hidden/Visible depending on the CheckBox.IsChecked property.

The IsChecked and the IsEnabled properties of the CheckBox itself are binded to the SelectedItem property of the first ComboBox in the first instance of the UserControl - such as: if the value is null they will be false. I'm using MVVM so this binding is defined on the ViewModel part.

My question is - is there a way to access the SelectedIndex property of one of the ComboBox of the UserControl through the XAML in the MainWindow, so when the CheckBox  is UnChecked, except that the second instance of the UserControl will turn to Hidden, the SelectedIndex of the ComboBox within the **second** instance will turn to 0?

The UserControl XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboField" ItemsSource="{Binding Fields}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Key"
          SelectedItem="{Binding FieldComboSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<TextBox x:Name="tbFirstValue"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="comboQueryType"
          SelectedItem="{Binding QueryTypeComboSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<TextBox x:Name="tbSecondValue"/>
```

The 2 instances and the CheckBox in the MainWindow XAML:

```
<local:FilterUC x:Name="firstFilter"/>    
<local:FilterUC x:Name="secondFilter">
    <local:FilterUC.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:FilterUC}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked,
                               ElementName=cbTwoFields}" Value="False">
                     <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                 <!--This is what I want to achieve:-->
                     <!--<Setter ElementName="comboField"
                                 Property="SelectedIndex" Value="0" />-->
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </local:FilterUC.Style>
</local:FilterUC>
<CheckBox x:Name="cbTwoFields" Content="Add filter" 
          IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=firstFilter, 
                              Path=DataContext.AddFilterEnable}" 
          IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=firstFilter, 
                              Path=DataContext.AddFilterChecked}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always just add a `DependencyProperty` to expose the `ComboBox.SelectedIndex` property:

```
public static DependencyProperty SelectedIndexProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "SelectedIndex", typeof(int), typeof(FilterUC), new PropertyMetadata(0));

public int SelectedIndex
{
    get { return (int)GetValue(SelectedIndexProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedIndexProperty, value); }
}
```

You didn't say which `ComboBox` you wanted to reset, so I'll just use this one to demonstrate how you should bind the `ComboBox.SelectedIndex` property to the new `DependencyProperty` using a `RelativeSource Binding`:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboQueryType" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:FilterUC}}}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding QueryTypeComboSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Then you *should* be able to access it in the `DataTrigger`. Try this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:FilterUC}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked,
                       ElementName=cbTwoFields}" Value="False">
             <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
             <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="0" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer.

I've tested the solution proposed, and it should have worked. It seems that the 
'<Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="0" />'
is being ignored somehow. (the first one behaves just as expected though).

I've tried to find a workaround, but with no success. I'd appreciate your further assistance or a working little demonstration.

Thanks a lot.